# PHP regex - get latitude and longitude

Tags: php, regex, google-maps

I wanna get from a page 2 values - lat and long. The source code contains this piece of JS:

```
new GLatLng(53.299671, -6.267786)
```

Can anyone suggest me the best method/regex?

Comment: @genesis: Probably those values in brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$input = "new GLatLng(53.299671, -6.267786)"; 
preg_match("~GLatLng\(([0-9\.\-]+).*?([\.\-0-9]+)\)~i", $input, $match); 

echo $match[1]." and ".$match[2];
```

Comment: thanks a lot and how to get those matched values? $match[1] and $match[2]?

Comment: If I helped you, please help me: **[accept my answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6V5xR.gif)** (click on that link if you're not sure how to do so)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
preg_match("/\(([\d-.]*), ([\d-.]*)\)/",$subject,$matches);
```